# WebView: Can't login into a http website with login & pass. Phone navigator can do it

Tags: android, ssl, webview, android-webview, ssl-certificate

I need to show a webview that let the user enter this website: http://m.orange.es/area_clientes/

If I try to enter to that website and login with my user with the phone navigator, it works fine, and the navigator asks me to accept a certificate.

If I try to enter that website and login with a webview in my android app, the webview can't do the login with my user and my password, the "accept certificate" popup does not appear, and I'm getting redirected to a error website.

How can this be solved?

I checked a lot of questions on stackoverflow related with this isseue, but none of them worked:

[WebView with SSL Client Certificate on Android 4 ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683643/webview-with-ssl-client-certificate-on-android-4-ics)

[Does the Web View on Android support SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977977/does-the-web-view-on-android-support-ssl)

[Android WebView SSL 'Security Warning'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630445/android-webview-ssl-security-warning)

http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/

My webview:

```
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom( allowZooming );
        webView.loadUrl(URLParser.parse(this.URL));
        webView.getLayoutParams().height=LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        webView.getLayoutParams().width=LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        /////////////////////
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);        
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        /////////////////////

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){       

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                handler.proceed();
            }

        });
```

Comment: I'm having similiar issues. Did you ever resolve this?